# What does "cheery fire" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In The Markenmore Mystery (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, a man was receiving his visitor

> Blick nodded affably to his shy and watchful visitor, and pointed to a chair close to his own by the **cheery** fire.

It's mentioned many times throughout the story, **"cheery fire" and "cheery blaze"**, so does it mean something like "bright"

Comment: Have you looked up "cheery" in a dictionary? What did it say, and why are you confused?

Comment: It says "pleasant or happy", but the normal description of fires are "bright, warm and so on" @randomhead

Comment: @AhmedSamir - Now you know another way to describe a fire. Try to imagine: a cold winter's night, you are happy to be in a cosy place near a warm fire. You can say it is a cheerful fire. Also colours - a cheerful red shirt. Also perhaps the kettle boiled merrily on the stove.

Comment: @AhmedSamir - you actually wrote 'It says "pleasant or happy"'. If it is cold and dark outside, a fire can certainly be 'pleasant'.

Comment: "Bright fire" or "fire that makes you cheerful"?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [**metonymy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) (specifically [**hypallage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage)), or a figure of speech that associates one thing with the name of another. The fire, being inanimate, cannot be humanly cheery but is associated with a pleasant or happy setting.